# an ipython tag? really?

Tags: discussion, tagging

is it appropriate to tag a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7496/) [ipython]? I understand that the question had to do with ipython, but in-fact it was a question about code listing and verbatim (both tags are there). The specific ipython tag seem to be irrelevant for this website.

So this question has two parts:

1. Should we remove the ipython tag from that question?
2. Whats the general approach to over-specification of tags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Remove the tag. It seems silly to tag every listing with the name of the language in the listing.
2. Remove them?

Comment: I agree with this, but will wait to see if there are any counterarguments before doing anything that requires moderator tools.

Comment: @andrew overtagging is one reason why we limit users to 5 tags. You should have seen what happened when we allowed 10+ tags..

Comment: @Andrew. This seems pretty clear to me, and I don't think needs the mod tools anyway.

Comment: @Joseph: I was thinking of removing the ipython tag from the tag list.  Maybe it will just go away once there are no questions tagged with it, I don't know.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes it will become inaccessible for users under 150 rep (or so) and will not be suggested for other users (like the {latex}-tag that was removed that way).

Comment: I've now made the change

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, it is strange to have [ipython](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipython) without [python](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).  The general question is, do we want specific programming language tags just for listings?  Obviously, languages like C, Lua, R, and Pascal, are relevant here for other reasons, and a code question might be relevant for them.

We could make the tags for some programming languages into synonyms for a generic code markup tag, say [code-layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-layout).  If we did this, it might be nice if we could try to make it so that all code layout questions had one from a limited list of tags.

**Postscript**

It occurs to me that there is a benefit to having lots of language-specific tags, even if they have only one or two questions falling under them, namely, they are visible and relevant results for SX-wide tag sets, such as [python jython](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/188/tagged-questions).  These could conceivably attract many people to the site.

Comment: Well, certainly it would make sense for e.g. Haskell -- there is at least one package dedicated to fancy dolled-up Haskell listings, which can be instructed to replace particular Haskell identifiers with whatever you want (typically this would be used to replace a Haskell operator made with an appropriate math symbol which looks somewhat similar, possibly made by squishing the symbols from the ASCII form together).

Comment: @Sam: Oddly enough, we had a qn on squashing Haskell operators: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/how-to-typeset-haskell-operator-and-friends